# How to scaffold generic web api 2 controller to use existing project that contains EF entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Inside Visual Studio 2012 i would like to create a solution with these projects

- project `Dal` contains the entities (mostly [DTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object) with a few complex objects) and the entity framework reference to persist the entities into the database
- project `WebApi` should contain the web services to fire [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) against `Dal`
- project `RichClient` is a Windows Forms Client to display and edit some data using the WebApi-Project
- project `WebClient` is a MVC5 Asp.Net page to view and edit the data as well

The code below is pseudo code. The idea is to use the existing entity framework project to take care of talking to the database.

```
public class EntityController<T> where T : ApiController 
{    
    // GET api/entity
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(){
        return Dal.GetEntitiesAsIEnumerable<T>();
    }

    // GET api/entity/5
    public string Get(int id){
        return Dal.GetEntity<T>(5);
    }

    // POST api/entity
    public int Post([FromBody]string value){
        var entity = GetEntityFromPost<T>();
        return Dal.Save<T>(entity);
    }

    // PUT api/entity/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value){
        var entity = GetEntityFromPut<T>();
        return Dal.Save<T>(entity);
    }

    // DELETE api/entity/5
    public void Delete(int id){
        var entity = GetEntityFromDelete<T>();
        return Dal.Delete<T>(entity.Id);
    }
}
```

### My questions are

- how can i scaffold the Web API 2.0 controller to use the already existing DAL-Project?
- can i use a generic controller using [a generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) like above?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's as simple as adding the DAL assembly reference to your WebApi project and then invoke the DAL as usual with the `using` statement.
2. You could use generics like in your example. But why would you? It's unnecessarily complex and a misuse of the language feature. Why not just use the MVC framework as intended and simply inherit from `ApiController`? Like this:

`public class EntityController : ApiController`